# Removing strings in XML using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML as below. I would like to remove the xA and x9 which corresponds to LF and tab in the variable para-no which currently is showing in the output:

```
<p class="Judg-1"><a id="&#xA;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;[1]&#xA;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;"></a></p>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Judgment>
    <Para level="1" no="1" pID="p1_1" indent="none">
        <Text indent="none" align="left">Paragraph 1</Text>
    </Para>
</Judgment>
```

This is the XSLT. I have commented out the multiple substring-after which does not seem to work in this case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="portlet"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="Judgment//Para[@level=1]/Text[position() = 1] | Annex//Para[@level=1]/Text[position() = 1]">
        <p class="Judg-1">
            <xsl:variable name="para-no">
                <!--[<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(../@pID,'p1_'), '&#xA;'), '&#x9;')"/>]-->
                [<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(../@pID,'p1_')"/>]
            </xsl:variable>
            <a id="{$para-no}"></a>
        </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want to use `translate` e.g. `translate($para-no, '&xA;&x9;', '')`.

Or better simply use `<xsl:variable name="para-no" select="concat('[', substring-after(../@pID,'p1_'), ']')"/>` instead of filling up the variable with a result tree fragment.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the suggestion. I tried [<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after(../@pID,'p1_'), '&#xA;&#x9;', '')"/>] on http://xsltransform.net/ but it still returns the xA etc.

Comment: @Eugene, I misread the original intent and input data, see whether the edit helps to either avoid constructing the contents with all those tabs/line breaks or if you want to continue to use `xsl:variable/xsl:value-of` to then use `translate` on the `$para-no`.